# Memory Leak on BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, delegates

1) I heard that when we won't call EndInvoke() it may lead  to memory leak? can you demonstrate it how could  this lead to memory leak?

2) When i suppose to call EndInvoke() shall i use the code like following ?

```
namespace BlockMechanism
{
    public delegate int MyDelegate(List<int> someInts);
    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
           List<int> someInts = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
           MyDelegate test = FinalResult;
           IAsyncResult res=test.BeginInvoke(someInts, null, test);
           Console.WriteLine(test.EndInvoke(res));
           Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        public static int FinalResult(List<int> Mylist)
        {
            return Mylist.Sum();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your example is correct there is no benefit from using a different thread because you call `EndInvoke` on the main thread which will block until the operation completes and it cannot do other work. It would have been equivalent if you called `Invoke` on the delegate or directly the `FinalResult` method itself. Usually `EndInvoke` is called in the callback provided by the `BeginInvoke` method:

```
class Program
{
    public delegate int MyDelegate(List<int> someInts);
    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<int> someInts = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
            MyDelegate test = FinalResult;
            test.BeginInvoke(someInts, ar => 
            {
                MyDelegate del = (MyDelegate)ar.AsyncState;
                Console.WriteLine(del.EndInvoke(ar));
            }, test);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        public static int FinalResult(List<int> Mylist)
        {
            return Mylist.Sum();
        }
    }
}
```

As far as the memory leak is concerned you may take a look at this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/b18b0a27-e2fd-445a-bcb3-22a315cd6f0d/).

P.S: Instance members of the [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class are not thread safe so you should be careful when you access them from multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN article on Begin/EndInvoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(VS.80).aspx)

Basically, if you don't call `EndInvoke()` you run the risk of leaking *something*.  Generally either memory, or a forever stalled thread in a pool somewhere.

The article discusses four common ways of using `BeginInvoke()` and when you should call `EndInvoke()` for each.

For posterity, I'll reproduce them here:

- Do some work and then call EndInvoke to block until the call completes.
- Obtain a WaitHandle using the System.IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle property, use its WaitOne method to block execution until the WaitHandle is signaled, and then call EndInvoke.
- Poll the IAsyncResult returned by BeginInvoke to determine when the asynchronous call has completed, and then call EndInvoke.
- Pass a delegate for a callback method to BeginInvoke. The method is executed on a ThreadPool thread when the asynchronous call completes. The callback method calls EndInvoke.